# Dense matrix vs sparse matrix, when they have same number of nonzero elements

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-analysis-of-pde

I came across a new way in the literature to solve PDE problems numerically, which is called 'Patch Reconstruction'. One example paper is: Li, R., Sun, Z., Yang, F., & Yang, Z. (2019). [A finite element method by patch reconstruction for the Stokes problem using mixed formulations](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2018.12.017). Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics, 353, 1-20.

Compared with the usual finite element method(DG), it has only one degree of freedom per element. But when it comes to the linear system to get the solution at last, namely Ax=b, the total number of nonzero elements remain the same, although dimension is smaller. So my question could be reduced to this question: comparing linear systems $A_1 x=b_1$ and  $A_2 x =b_2$, if $A_1$ and $A_2$ have same number of nonzero elements but dimension is different ($\dim(A_1)=2\dim(A_2)$), solving which linear system is more efficient? Here I could not consider anything about condition number or precondition because they are still in need of further research.

Comment: The question is probably too general to have a very precise answer.  Some of the important unspecified aspects (in addition to the ones you have mentioned) are whether the matrices are small enough for direct solvers to be effective and what is the structure of the sparse matrix.  But you could try asking on scicomp.SE, where there are some experts in numerical linear algebra.